# GAN training of a model to generate 3d models from 4 anthropometric input(height,waist,chest,hip)

Tags: machine-learning

```
# Training loop
num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch in train_dataloader:
        real_data = batch
        fake_data = generator(anthropometric_tensor)  # Replace with actual input

        # Train discriminator
        optim_d.zero_grad()
        real_labels = torch.ones(real_data.size(0), 1)
        fake_labels = torch.zeros(fake_data.size(0), 1)
        loss_real = criterion(discriminator(real_data), real_labels)
        loss_fake = criterion(discriminator(fake_data.detach()), fake_labels)
        loss_D = loss_real + loss_fake
        loss_D.backward()
        optimizer_D.step()

        # Train generator
        optimizer_G.zero_grad()
        loss_G = criterion(discriminator(fake_data), real_labels)
        loss_G.backward()
        optimizer_G.step()

    print(f"Epoch [{epoch}/{num_epochs}] Loss_D: {loss_D.item()} Loss_G: {loss_G.item()}")
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 37500]' is invalid for input of size 64
```